# Sumifs <> not operating as an AND function

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have two criteria columns with data I want to exclude, but the result of my sumifs is wrong when I enter the two criteria. When I concatenate the two columns and use a sumifs with one criteria (could also use a sumif), then the result is correct.

I would like to sum col1 where col2 is not "a" and where col3 is not "b". The formula I have used is `=SUMIFS(A9:A12,B9:B12,"<>a",C9:C12,"<>b")` which returns 0.

`=SUMIFS(A9:A12,D9:D12,"<>ab")` returns 7, which is correct.

I understood that `SUMIFS` runs on an `AND` operator so all conditions must be true, but in the first case with two criteria it excludes all of the numbers because everything in col3 is a "b".

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1        a        b      ab
2        b        b      bb
3        a        b      ab
5        d        b      db
```

Why am I getting different results? When I do the same formula but as inclusive such as `=SUMIFS(A9:A12,B9:B12,"a",C9:C12,"b")` and `=SUMIFS(A9:A12,D9:D12,"ab")`, both formulas return 4 which is correct. But using `<>` provides mismatched answers.

Comment: col3 is always b, so your second criterion always fails, hence the 0.

Comment: So then the formula evaluates the formulas on a criteria by criteria basis, not summing as a true AND? I was under the impression my formula would sum where col2 <> a AND where col3 <> b. I understand that all in col3 is b, but I thought by applying the first criteria this changes?

Comment: No, it is a true AND. So each row has to meet **both** criteria and none of your rows match the second criteria. What it *doesn't* do is combine the two columns and the two criteria and then do a single comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All formulas in your question give correct results.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1        a        b      ab       // a<>a false, b<>b false -> no summing
2        b        b      bb       // b<>a true , b<>b false -> no summing
3        a        b      ab       // a<>a false, b<>b false -> no summing
5        d        b      db       // d<>a true , b<>b false -> no summing
```

Try to change the second line to:

```
2        b        e      be       // b<>a true , b<>e true
```

You will see that the result will change.